# Unrecognized token near "@" using SQLITE in C#

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am using **SQLITE database in C#** for maintaining data.
I am facing issue with the error:

> **unrecognized token near "@"** while adding it to database.
>   i tried with the **\@** but it does not support.
>
> **unrecognized token near "@"**
>   **unrecognized token near "^"** etc.

I also want to know all such characters which is unrecognized.

Query:

```
INSERT INTO FOLDER_TABLE([FolderName],[FolderPath]) values(@#$%^&_()_+!          __.;............,33346,'\\All fields.pst\IPMRoot\Top of Personal Folders\!@#$%25^&_()_+{}_;._;`[]_-=\_;`[]{}\@#$%25^&_()_+!_.;............\')
```

Is anyone having solution for this issue.
Please suggest,
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `VALUES(@#...` should probably be something like `VALUES('@#...` and you'll want to use parameters but failing that escape special characters like `'` within the string.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, strings must be surround with single quotes (and quotes in the string must be escaped by doubling them):

```
INSERT INTO FOLDER_TABLE([FolderName],[FolderPath])
VALUES('@#$%^&_()_+!          __.;............,33346',
       '\\All fields.pst\IPMRoot\Top of Personal Folders\!@#$%25^&_()_+{}_;._;`[]_-=\_;`[]{}\@#$%25^&_()_+!_.;............\')
```